# All inclusive MySQL data validation

Tags: php, mysql, database, validation, input

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

I am building my first online shop and i'm writing the PHP code myself and using a MySQL database. I have been advised that its really important to have data validation on inputs so that my database cannot be compromised.  Can someone tell me what validation to include or maybe a trusted tutorial that is recommended.

Thanks in advance

Comment: unrelated to security, but you might also want to look into supporting utf8: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search this site for "Sql Injection". A common source of sql injection attacks is user-input which is not validated and is then trustingly concatenated before being sent to the database.

For example, if your statement is this:

```
select col1, col2 from mytable where id =' + <some variable> + ' and xyz = abc
```

(where 'some variable' is user input just passed on to the SQL)

then the user can input `'xxx''; delete from mytable; --'`

and what the database gets is:

```
select col1, col2 from mytable 
where id ='xxx'; delete from mytable; --' and xyz = abc
```

causing havoc.

So the key issue here is: **don't pass unvalidated, concatenated text to your database for it to execute**.

You can achieve this in several ways:

- check the input for unwanted characters (difficult to cover
  everthing)
- build your SQL as parameterized SQL i.e. binding user input to
  parameters
- invoke stored procedures (I like them but they are not everyone's cup
  of tea)

I'd go for parameterized SQL as the database driver will take care of binding *everything* the user inputs as a single value, whilst at the same time keeping your business logic out of the database.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql Validation means you have to prevent your queries from MySql injection. Please read the following to avoid mysql Injection.

http://rosstanner.co.uk/2012/01/php-mysql-preventing-mysql-injection/